# Cant use docx module: expections

Tags: python-3.x, module, terminal, docx, python-docx

In pycharm:

```
from docx import Document
```

This is the error im getting:

```
/Users/XYZ/PycharmProjects/XYZ/venv/bin/python "/Users/XYZ/PycharmProjects/XYZ/Intro - Hello World.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XYZ/PycharmProjects/XYZ/Intro - Hello World.py", line 1, in <module>
    from docx import Document
  File "/Users/XYZ/PycharmProjects/XYZ/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docx.py", line 30, in <module>
    from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I go to the directory -> site packages -> docx -> 
I can find the file "exceptions.py".  I do not know why it says it is missing.

Comment: This can happen if you have a `docx.py` file in the current directory or a `docx/` folder (that I suppose would have an `__init__.py` file in it). If not, it's an installation problem. I would uninstall and reinstall using the package manager for your environment. Make sure you install it into your virtual environment if you're using one (looks like you are) and that the virtual environment is active when you run your program. Probably easier to debug if you get it running from the command line first, then work on getting it to work in PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks, I just found out that when I created the new project it automatically was created using Virtualenv (can not understand yet what a virtual environment is) but apparently creating a new project using the project interpreter Python 3.7 fixes this problem. If you can explain further about this to me I would really appreciate it.